# Iterate Over List of Objects but Insert a Calculated Value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

THANKS IN ADVANCE FOR ANY HELP!  I always upvote btw

So I have this list of members

```
export const currentMembers= {
  'A1': {
    'memberStartDate': 0,
    'currentContractEndDate': 0,
    'flagged': false,
    'notes': 'Some Notes about member',
    'memberId': 'A1',
  },
  'A2': {
    'memberStartDate': 1454306400000,
    'currentContractEndDate': 1501747600000,
    'notes': 'Some Notes about member',
    'flagged': false,
    'memberId': 'A2',
  },
  'A3': {
    'memberStartDate': 1454306400000,
    'currentContractEndDate': 1502747600000,    
    'notes': 'Some Notes about member',
    'flagged': false,
    'memberId': 'A3',
  },
}
```

I'm trying to write a function that will return me the same list, but with an inserted calculated value, like THIS:

```
export const currentMembersModified = {
  'A1': {
    'memberStartDate': 0,
    'currentContractEndDate': 0,
    'daysRemainingInContract': 0,  // calculated from currentMembers object above
    'flagged': false,
    'notes': 'Some Notes about member',
    'memberId': 'A1',
  },
  'A2': {
    'memberStartDate': 1454306400000,
    'currentContractEndDate': 1501747600000,
    'daysRemainingInContract': 123,  // calculated from currentMembers object above
    'notes': 'Some Notes about member',
    'flagged': false,
    'memberId': 'A2',
  },
  'A3': {
    'memberStartDate': 1454306400000,
    'currentContractEndDate': 1502747600000,
    'daysRemainingInContract': 234, // calculated from currentMembers object above
    'notes': 'Some Notes about member',
    'flagged': false,
    'memberId': 'A3',
  },
}
```

I've been trying:

```
const modifiedMembers = Object.keys(currentMembers).forEach(key => {
  const currentMemberObject = currentMembers[key]

  const currentDate = new Date()
  const currentEndDate = currentMembers[key].currentContractEndDate
  const calculatedDateStuff = currentEndDate - currentDate

  return {stuff I don't know how to do}
})
```

THANKS!

Comment: Something like this? http://jsbin.com/jeriqefaxo/1/edit?js,console

Comment: All great suggestions, I'll give them a try tonight when I get home from work!  I'm using create-react-app / react / redux so immutability is essential.

Comment: @Gerardo EXCELLENT!!  Exactly what I was needing!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using babel with your react project, then depending in what stages you are including, then you might try something like this:

```
var newMembers; // new object/state
Object.keys(currentMembers).forEach((key) => {
  var calculatedDays = currentMembers[key].currentContractEndDate - 21343214213; // or whatever logic you need here
  var member = {};
  member[key] = {
        ...currentMembers[key],
      calculatedDays
    }
  newMembers = {
    ...newMembers,
    ...member
  }
});
```

This uses the spread operator combine objects. ES6 currently only allows for iterables to be combined using the spread operator, but using them with objects thanks to babel is a common React pattern, as it means you can avoid changing the original object.

Comment: Your example does *not* use object destructing. You are using *spread properties* which are an *experimental feature* and not part of ES6.

Comment: @FelixKling yeah, I realisd that after I posted. I just had object destructuring on the mind. Will fix that up now. Will also change the ES6 line to clear things up.

Comment: Worked Perfect!  THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution but if you want to keep orignal copy of `currentMembers`, use `Object.assign()` or ES6 spread operator to make a copy of that.

```
for (key in currentMembers) {
  var currentMemberObject = currentMembers[key]

  var currentDate = new Date()
  var currentEndDate = currentMembers[key].currentContractEndDate
  var calculatedDateStuff = currentEndDate - currentDate;
  // fix logic to calculate number of days yourself, however, here is how
  // you need to update those objects
  currentMembers[key]['daysRemainingInContract'] = calculatedDateStuff
}

console.log(currentMembers);
```

Comment: you could also use `currentMemberObject.daysRemainingInContract = calculatedDateStuff` to set the value

Answer (score 1):

You can use `for..of` loop, `Object.entries()`, `Object.assign()` approach by [@Norris](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20082660/) at [How do I get the number of days between two dates in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542938/how-do-i-get-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-javascript)

```js
const currentMembersModified = new Object;

const currentMembers= {
  'A1': {
    'memberStartDate': 0,
    'currentContractEndDate': 0,
    'flagged': false,
    'notes': 'Some Notes about member',
    'memberId': 'A1',
  },
  'A2': {
    'memberStartDate': 1454306400000,
    'currentContractEndDate': 1501747600000,
    'notes': 'Some Notes about member',
    'flagged': false,
    'memberId': 'A2',
  },
  'A3': {
    'memberStartDate': 1454306400000,
    'currentContractEndDate': 1502747600000,    
    'notes': 'Some Notes about member',
    'flagged': false,
    'memberId': 'A3',
  }
}

for (const [key, prop] of Object.entries(currentMembers)) {

  const {memberStartDate, currentContractEndDate} = prop;  
 
  const [to, from] = [
    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/20082660/
    Math.floor(new Date(currentContractEndDate).getTime() / (3600*24*1000)),
    Math.floor(new Date(memberStartDate).getTime() / (3600*24*1000))
  ];
  
  Object.assign(currentMembersModified
  , {[key]:Object.assign({}, prop, {daysRemainingInContract: to - from})});
  
}

console.log(currentMembersModified);
```